# How to convert a BufferedImage to a certain colour?

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, filter, rgb

Speicifically I have images that are all solid black on transparent. I want to assign an abritrary colour to the images when they are drawn so that the black areas are changed to the new colour.

I tried using a RGBImageFilter that just returned the colour I want but something's going wrong and nothing is being drawn at all. (ColourFilter extends RGBImageFilter and just returns the set colour in it's filterRGB() method.)

```
BufferedImage tileImage = _tiles.get( tileID );
ColourFilter cFilt = new ColourFilter();
cFilt.setColour( colour );
FilteredImageSource filteredSrc = new FilteredImageSource( tileImage.getSource(), cFilt );
Image finalImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(filteredSrc);
bufferGraphics2D.drawImage(finalImage.....
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  For the source image, generate it in code (should only take a couple of lines of code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [AlphaComposites](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html), particularly DST_IN:

```
BufferedImage original = ... // dimensions width x height, black on transparent

// create red image
BufferedImage redVersion = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) redVersion.getGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

// paint original with composite
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstIn);
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, null);

// redVersion is now a red version of original
```

Comment: Can you post a compilable and runnable version of your example, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?  For example of one, please see my example.

Comment: This method turns the black pixels to the desired colour but turns all the full transparent pixels black. All I want to change is the opaque pixels. [SSCCE Test I did. I think..](http://pastebin.com/Jz7MSnxQ)

Comment: @Stretch: Painting directly to a graphics component works differently than painting to a BufferedImage.  Here's a version using an image in a JLabel instead of paintComponent: http://pastebin.com/aHE8NTsj

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but image filters and should be able to do what *I think* you are trying to do. For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorSwap {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final String mapUrlPath = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/"
               + "wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Maps-for-free_Sierra_Nevada.png";

      try {
         URL mapUrl = new URL(mapUrlPath);
         BufferedImage mapImage = ImageIO.read(mapUrl);
         Image newMapImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
                           new FilteredImageSource(mapImage.getSource(),
                                    new XorFilter()));

         Image grayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
                  new FilteredImageSource(mapImage.getSource(),
                           new MyGrayFilter()));

         Image grayToColorImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
                  new FilteredImageSource(grayImage.getSource(),
                           new GrayToColorFilter(Color.red)));

         ImageIcon mapIcon = new ImageIcon(mapImage);
         ImageIcon newMapIcon = new ImageIcon(newMapImage);
         ImageIcon newGrayIcon = new ImageIcon(grayImage);

         ImageIcon grayToColorIcon = new ImageIcon(grayToColorImage);

         JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
         imagePanel.add(new JLabel(mapIcon));
         imagePanel.add(new JLabel(newMapIcon));
         imagePanel.add(new JLabel(newGrayIcon));
         imagePanel.add(new JLabel(grayToColorIcon));

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, imagePanel, "Image Color Swap",
                  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}

class RedBlueSwapFilter extends RGBImageFilter {
   public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
      return ((rgb & 0xff00ff00) | ((rgb & 0xff0000) >> 16) | ((rgb & 0xff) << 16));
   }
}

class XorFilter extends RGBImageFilter {
   public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int argb) {
      return ((argb & 0xff000000) | (argb ^ 0x00ffffff));
   }
}

class MyGrayFilter extends RGBImageFilter {
   public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int argb) {
      int r = (argb & 0x00ff0000) >> 0x10;
      int g = (argb & 0x0000ff00) >> 0x08;
      int b = (argb & 0x000000ff);
      int ave = (r + g + b) / 3;

      return ((argb & 0xff000000) | (ave << 0x10 | ave << 0x08 | ave));
   }
}

class GrayToColorFilter extends RGBImageFilter {
   private Color c;

   public GrayToColorFilter(Color c) {
      this.c = c;
   }

   public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int argb) {
      return (argb | c.getRGB());
   }

}
```

Comment: I think a filter like this should do what I want but I'm mostly unfamiliar with bitwise operators. The GrayToColorFilter seems like what I want but it's not quite set up right and just fills the image with the set colour.

Comment: @Stretch, as has been already suggested, show us an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org), and we'll better be able to help you. This isn't asking too much, since I'm only asking you to put in the same effort that I've done in creating my SSCCE above. Please click on the link for specifics. Oh, and after you've edited your original post and have posted your SSCCE, please comment us so we'll know to look for it and help you out.

Comment: I appreciate your help and your efforts but I fail to see how I can do that. Anything I do would just be exactly the same as the code you've posted here, with a large question mark in the filterRGB function..

Comment: @Stretch: If it were me and I were stuck and still needed help, I'd at least attempt to create an SSCCE and post my attempt, as I'd have nothing to lose in the effort, but that's completely up to you. For now, I guess we're at an impasse. Best of luck regardless.