# java buffered image color op with different values for RGB

Tags: java, colors, bufferedimage

I have a buffered image that is drawn in grayscale, and I would like to convert it to color, where the colors map to some ranges in the gray. For example, all grays between 0-100 map to red, 100-255 map to green. It looks like the buffered image lookup ops are the way to do this, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this. For example, if the RGB of the grayscale image is (50,50,50), I want to convert that pixel to (255,0,0), not (255,255,255). Is the lookup op the right way to go with this?

Comment: The `LookupOp` is rather intended for cases where *each* color is individually mapped to *one* other color. So based on the description, it sounds like an approach as in Braj's answer could be more suitable here. You could replace the query `if(red==50...)` with `if (red<50...)` to really treat color *ranges*. If your intention is to "tint"/"dye" the image (keeping the lighness of all pixels the same, but giving them certain colors) it might be a bit more complicated. If this is the case, you should point it out in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the RGB of the grayscale image is (50,50,50), I want to convert that pixel to (255,0,0)

Try this one

```
try {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Tulips.jpg"));
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    int newColorRGB = new Color(255, 0, 0).getRGB();
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
            int red = color.getRed();
            int blue = color.getBlue();
            int green = color.getGreen();

            if (red == 50 && blue == 50 && green == 50) {
                newImage.setRGB(x, y, newColorRGB);
            } else {
                newImage.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(newImage, "png", new File("resources/Tulips1.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Sorry, I cannot find that file.");
}
```

Note: change the image type as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do the trick. Wasn't sure if there was a less "brute force" way to do it.

Comment: For more info have a look at [How to convert a BufferedImage to a certain colour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853384/how-to-convert-a-bufferedimage-to-a-certain-colour). @Hovercraft Full Of Eels has posted some sample code using `RGBImageFilter`.